# How to get the list of available collections/packages/libraries for `ng add` (angular/cli)?

Tags: angular, collections, package, command-line-interface, addition

How can I get the list of available collections/packages/libraries for

`ng add <collection>`

Is there also the possibility to search for existing packages?

Comment: Installs any npm package. I think if looks for a `collections.json` file to see if it supports schematics. https://www.npmjs.com/